# Deserialize struct with serde when a members enum tag is at the outermost level?

Tags: enums, rust, yaml, deserialization, serde

I have a struct containing an enum that I am trying to deserialize from YAML using serde:

```rust
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Foo {
    common: String,
    #[serde(flatten)]
    bar: Bar,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
#[serde(rename_all = "snake_case")]
enum Bar {
    BarA(BarA),
    BarB(BarB),
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct BarA {
    a: String,
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug, PartialEq)]
struct BarB {
    b: String,
}
```

```
[dependencies]
serde = { version = "1", features = ["derive"] }
serde_yaml = "0.8"
```

The code compiles, but for it to deserialize properly, the YAML needs to look like this:

```
common: Hello
bar_a:
  a: World
```

The problem is that my YAML looks like this:

```
bar_a:
  common: Hello
  a: World
```

Note that the enum tag is at the outermost level, outside the struct. How can I deserialize from that format? My enum is rather long (20+ variants), so I would prefer to avoid anything that would require more boilerplate code.

To be clear, I am looking for something that pass the following test:

```rust
#[cfg(test)]
#[test]
fn test() {
    let input = r#"
        bar_a:
          common: Hello
          a: World
    "#;

    let foo: Foo = serde_yaml::from_str(&input).unwrap();

    assert_eq!(
        foo,
        Foo {
            common: "Hello".to_string(),
            bar: Bar::BarA(BarA {
                a: "World".to_string()
            })
        }
    );
}
```

[Here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=dc0ad7794f3f25df161a5cfd959df403) it is on the Rust Playground.

Comment: I think this structure is different enough from the derived `Deserialize` and `Serialize` impls that you can't just fix it up with attributes. You almost certainly need to implement those traits manually.

Comment: @PeterHall Thanks for the input! I fear you are correct... I really have no clue how to, though.

Comment: Please provide more exemple, it's unclear what format you want.

Comment: Why must your Rust structure be as you have specified? Why not follow the pattern laid out in the YAML?

Comment: @Shepmaster Because there is some common behaviour related to the member I called `common` here (in reality, there are more common ones). I want the struct `Foo` to first take care of the common behaviour, and then pass on to the different `Bar` for the specifics. Did not include everything in the question in an attempt to keep it "minimal". If you want to, I can update with more code that makes this clearer?

Comment: [You can embed the complex logic and still use it from outside](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=493a0d3e111d62fe60c943d5330c5b0e)

Comment: @Shepmaster Thanks - interesting idea! I remember reading somewhere that using the Deref trait for anything but smart pointers is an anti pattern, but I can't really see why so... Anyways, I think this reallu does solve my problem and will be easier than trying to implement Deserialize, so feel free to post it as an answer if you want to.

Comment: *so feel free to post it as an answer* — that code snippet doesn't answer the question that you've asked ("Deserialize struct with serde when a members enum tag is at the outermost level?"), so it's wouldn't be appropriate to post it as such.